# Dropdown moving down on Handsontable

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I am having this bug in handsontable. I just realized this mornign this also happen in all handsontable demos and tables, i have tryied moving the dropdown arrow with css using ellipsis, positions, displays, etc.

[image: bug ht]

And this is how should be.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Pretty sure that is intended, how else should it be?

Comment: i have uploaded a new pic of how this should be.